# Selenium2Library; Browsers are not closing while scripts is running through command prompt

Tags: batch-file, robotframework, selenium2library

I am using IE browser for Automate my web application. 
It is working fine while running **Robot-framework** scripts through **RIDE**.
But problem is while it is running through batch file/Command prompt, Browsers aren't closing after suite teardown, or by calling **Close All Browsers** command.

Here is my batch file...

```
cd C:\myAutomation-Scripts
pybot --test * myAutoTestSuite.txt
```

But Test-cases is passing always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suite teardown seems to be not executed at all, is it?
I would say you want to run rather the suite in this case than separate test cases:
`pybot --suite myAutoTestSuite .`
If you need to run separate test case(s):
`pybot --test name1 .`

Comment: @ Jan, Thanks for your comments, It is now working as per your suggestion, but problem, is it is also closing the command prompt itself after end of the execution.
    **pybot --test  myTestcase  myTestSuite.txt**

Comment: Well, as I'm completely linux guy it is bit difficult for me to give you proper advice for any win-batch problem. Isn't `pause` the command for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file

Comment: Yes, 'pause' or 'cmd /k' command don't work for me, but anyhow this is not a big problem, I have to go to log or report file to see the overall status.

Comment: @LokmanLiton then please consider to accept and/or upvote my answer if you found it useful.