# Running Python file from C# Windows Form

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, winforms, ironpython

So I tried the methods that were mentioned in the previously asked similar question but none of them works for my python file. I have been on it for two days and can't seem to find a solution how to run this file from C# form on button click.

IronPython doesn't work because the python script has libraries that cannot be imported in Ironpython.

Running it from cmd doesn't work because cmd starts and then gets closed in a second.

Here's the code:

```
 import imutils
from imutils import face_utils
from utils import *
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pag
import imutils
import dlib
import cv2


# Thresholds and consecutive frame length for triggering the mouse action.
MOUTH_AR_THRESH = 0.3
MOUTH_AR_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES = 3
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.20
EYE_AR_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES = 5
WINK_AR_DIFF_THRESH = 0.001
WINK_AR_CLOSE_THRESH = 0.2
WINK_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES = 4

# Initialize the frame counters for each action as well as 
# booleans used to indicate if action is performed or not
MOUTH_COUNTER = 0
EYE_COUNTER = 0
WINK_COUNTER = 0
INPUT_MODE = False
EYE_CLICK = False
LEFT_WINK = False
RIGHT_WINK = False
SCROLL_MODE = False
ANCHOR_POINT = (0, 0)
WHITE_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW_COLOR = (0, 255, 255)
RED_COLOR = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN_COLOR = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE_COLOR = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)

# Initialize Dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
shape_predictor = "model/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(shape_predictor)

# Grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the left and
# right eye, nose and mouth respectively
(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]
(nStart, nEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["nose"]
(mStart, mEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["mouth"]

# Video capture
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
resolution_w = 1366
resolution_h = 768
cam_w = 640
cam_h = 480
unit_w = resolution_w / cam_w
unit_h = resolution_h / cam_h



while True:
    # Grab the frame from the threaded video file stream, resize
    # it, and convert it to grayscale
    # channels)
    _, frame = vid.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=cam_w, height=cam_h)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the grayscale frame
    rects = detector(gray, 0)

    # Loop over the face detections
    if len(rects) > 0:
        rect = rects[0]
    else:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        continue

    # Determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

    # Extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
    # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
    mouth = shape[mStart:mEnd]
    leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
    rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
    nose = shape[nStart:nEnd]

    # Because I flipped the frame, left is right, right is left.
    temp = leftEye
    leftEye = rightEye
    rightEye = temp

    # Average the mouth aspect ratio together for both eyes
    mar = mouth_aspect_ratio(mouth)
    leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
    rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)
    ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0
    diff_ear = np.abs(leftEAR - rightEAR)

    nose_point = (nose[3, 0], nose[3, 1])

    # Compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
    # visualize each of the eyes
    mouthHull = cv2.convexHull(mouth)
    leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
    rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [mouthHull], -1, YELLOW_COLOR, 1)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, YELLOW_COLOR, 1)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, YELLOW_COLOR, 1)

    for (x, y) in np.concatenate((mouth, leftEye, rightEye), axis=0):
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 2, GREEN_COLOR, -1)
        
    # Check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink
    # threshold, and if so, increment the blink frame counter
    if diff_ear > WINK_AR_DIFF_THRESH:

        if leftEAR < rightEAR:
            if leftEAR < EYE_AR_THRESH:
                WINK_COUNTER += 1

                if WINK_COUNTER > WINK_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES:
                    pag.click(button='left')

                    WINK_COUNTER = 0

        elif leftEAR > rightEAR:
            if rightEAR < EYE_AR_THRESH:
                WINK_COUNTER += 1

                if WINK_COUNTER > WINK_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES:
                    pag.click(button='right')

                    WINK_COUNTER = 0
        else:
            WINK_COUNTER = 0
    else:
        if ear <= EYE_AR_THRESH:
            EYE_COUNTER += 1

            if EYE_COUNTER > EYE_AR_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES:
                SCROLL_MODE = not SCROLL_MODE
                # INPUT_MODE = not INPUT_MODE
                EYE_COUNTER = 0

                # nose point to draw a bounding box around it

        else:
            EYE_COUNTER = 0
            WINK_COUNTER = 0

    if mar > MOUTH_AR_THRESH:
        MOUTH_COUNTER += 1

        if MOUTH_COUNTER >= MOUTH_AR_CONSECUTIVE_FRAMES:
            # if the alarm is not on, turn it on
            INPUT_MODE = not INPUT_MODE
            # SCROLL_MODE = not SCROLL_MODE
            MOUTH_COUNTER = 0
            ANCHOR_POINT = nose_point

    else:
        MOUTH_COUNTER = 0

    if INPUT_MODE:
        cv2.putText(frame, "READING INPUT!", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, RED_COLOR, 2)
        x, y = ANCHOR_POINT
        nx, ny = nose_point
        w, h = 60, 35
        multiple = 1
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - w, y - h), (x + w, y + h), GREEN_COLOR, 2)
        cv2.line(frame, ANCHOR_POINT, nose_point, BLUE_COLOR, 2)

        dir = direction(nose_point, ANCHOR_POINT, w, h)
        cv2.putText(frame, dir.upper(), (10, 90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, RED_COLOR, 2)
        drag = 18
        if dir == 'right':
            pag.moveRel(drag, 0)
        elif dir == 'left':
            pag.moveRel(-drag, 0)
        elif dir == 'up':
            if SCROLL_MODE:
                pag.scroll(40)
            else:
                pag.moveRel(0, -drag)
        elif dir == 'down':
            if SCROLL_MODE:
                pag.scroll(-40)
            else:
                pag.moveRel(0, drag)

    if SCROLL_MODE:
        cv2.putText(frame, 'SCROLL MODE IS ON!', (10, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, RED_COLOR, 2)


    # Show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # If the `Esc` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == 27:
        break

# Do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vid.release()
```

Comment: You can provide flags ing command prompt like /k so it doesn't close.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082797/10292075

Comment: @Goion I added it in the start.arguments line, doesn't work.

start.Arguments = @"/k   C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Gaze Controlled Desktop\mousecursorcontrol.py";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install your libraries in "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" or any python environment

and try this:

```
public string Run(string scriptFilePatch, string args)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"; // or any python environment

    psi.Arguments = $"\"{scriptFilePatch}\" {args}";

    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    string errors = "", result = "";

    using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    }
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result, writer);
    string decodedString = writer.ToString();

    return decodedString;
}
```

Usage:

```
 Run("c:/code/download.py", "\"imageUrl\" \"fileName}"");
```

and read the arguments in python whit this

Python Code :

```
import sys
url = sys.argv[1] #arg {imageUrl} recived from c# code
fileName = sys.argv[2] #arg {fileName} recived from c# code
```

and for return data to c# code you should use this :

```
b = any_object;
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytearray(b,"utf-8"))
```