# Seeing output of shell script in python via subprocess

Tags: python, bash

I have a simple shell file that has this:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello"
echo "Full Name: $1";
echo "Age: $2";
```

I am calling this file from the python jupyter notebook like this:

```
import subprocess
filePath = 'testScript.sh'
arg1 = 'John Doe'
arg2 = 2
subprocess.run([filePath, arg1, str(arg2)], shell=True, check=True)
```

The file runs fine and I get this output:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['testScript.sh', 'John Doe', '2'], returncode=0)
```

While the code is running, it pops open a command line window and the output flashes for a second before the window closes. I was wondering is there a way to print output into python rather than only seeing the output in the command line window? Or is there a way to prevent the command line window from closing so I can see the output?

Comment: Totally off-topic, but remove the semicolons from the Bash script. They do nothing there and you're not even using them consistently.

Comment: `shell=True` breaks your code here, assuming you're on something UNIXy.

Comment: ...that said, I assume this is Windows? On UNIXy systems, this wouldn't pop up a new command line window at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, this is on a windows system

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the capture_output keyword-argument to the subprocess.run() function.
Like this:

```
subprocess.run(["ls", "-a"], capture_output=True)
```

This would return a CompletedProcess instance with a property called `stdout`, which contains all the output.
In this case all the files and directories in the working directory.

Comment: I tried the stdout way but it doesn't print the right output, It shows output as: b''

Comment: You get a binary string?
I think there is some method to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to a file:

```
subdir = ... #<========= Path of executable

fout = open(os.path.join(subdir, "out.txt"), "w")
ferr = open(os.path.join(subdir, "err.txt"), "w")
p = subprocess.run(file_to_run, cwd=subdir, stdout=fout, stderr=ferr,)
```

Alternatively, you could add a `pause` at the end of your script (in Windows/DOS batch files). Ref: [How to prevent auto-closing of console after the execution of batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988403/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-console-after-the-execution-of-batch-file)

Comment: Hmm, this creates the out.txt and err.txt files as blank